# Elassandra - Kibana Issue in creating the index and Visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, kibana, elassandra

We tried integrating the Elassandra(2017-05-22 Release 2.4.5.1 Elasticsearch 2.4.5 + Cassandra 3.0.13
)with Kibana (4..6.4). But We are struggling to with the following issue.

```
 log   [10:01:51.003] [info][listening] Server running at http://XXXXXX:5601
  log   [10:01:55.983] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [10:02:00.913] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
  log   [10:02:00.941] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@1.0.0] Status changed from green to red - [document_already_exists_exception] [config][4.6.4]: document already exists, with: {"shard":"0","index":"kibana"}
health status index        pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size

green  open   emp            2   0          0            0       142b           142b
green  open   weatherindex   2   0          0            0       142b           142b
green  open   weatherts1     2   0          0            0       142b           142b
green  open   kibana         2   0          0            0       142b           142b
green  open   weatherts      2   0          0            0       142b          142b
```

Can any body please help to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior in Kibana on a elasticsearch-node with a higher-than-default refresh_interval.

The refresh interval is 1s by default. Putting a higher refresh interval can improve (indexing) performance, but causes changes to become visible later.

In this case, 1) kibana checks whether the .kibana index exists, 2) sees that it doesn't, 3) creates the .kibana index, 4) checks whether it exists, 5) wrongly concludes that it doesn't because the refresh_interval hasn't expired yet, back to 3) again.

Solutions:

- Wait refresh_interval seconds, after which kibana will continue to start.
- Restore refresh_interval to the default value of 1s (and accept the lower indexing performance).